# Creating an input file from an output file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert an output file from one program to be an input file for one program. A short piece of the output file is:

```
27
 1    1.614880   -3.344014    0.567880      1
 2   -4.885669   -2.351776   -0.165236      1
 3   -3.229517   -2.259459   -0.802815      3
```

The script attached below does this job perfectly fine. However, it does not take the 5th column into consideration. I am just wondering how I can make it so that it takes this into consideration. That is, when the 5th row has a value of 1, output the line as:

```
outfile.write('<marker id="{}" x="{}" y="{}" z="{}"'
              ' r="1" g="1" b="0" radius="0.125"/>\n'.format(index, x, y, z))
```

But when it has a value of 3, output the line as:

```
outfile.write('<marker id="{}" x="{}" y="{}" z="{}"'
              ' r="0" g="0" b="1" radius="0.125"/>\n'.format(index, x, y, z))
```

Code:

```
import sys
import glob

from os.path import exists

filenames = glob.glob("*.txt")

for filename in filenames:
    output = filename.replace(".txt", ".cmm")

    if exists(output):
        print("SKIPPED " + filename)
        continue

    with open(filename, "r") as infile:
        contents = infile.readlines()


    with open(output, "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write('<marker_set name="marker set 1">\n')

        for line in contents[1:]:
            line = line.replace("\n", "")
            line_split = line.split()

            index = line_split[0]
            x = float(line_split[1])*0.52918
            y = float(line_split[2])*0.52918
            z = float(line_split[3])*0.52918

            outfile.write('<marker id="{}" x="{}" y="{}" z="{}"'
                          ' r="1" g="1" b="0" radius="0.125"/>\n'.format(index, x, y, z))

        outfile.write('</marker_set>\n')
```

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "when the 5th row has a value of 1". It looks like each row has multiple columns. Do you mean that any of the columns can have a value of 1?

Comment: Please add a 5th row to your question to better illustrate what you mean.

Comment: @p3j4p5 I meant to say 5th column not row, my apologies.

Comment: @Cdc95 - Thanks, that makes sense - I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply write different lines depending on a what the fifth column contains, e.g.:

```python
...
with open(output, "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write('<marker_set name="marker set 1">\n')
    
    for line in contents[1:]:
        line = line.replace("\n", "")
        line_split = line.split()
            
        index = line_split[0]
        x = float(line_split[1])*0.52918
        y = float(line_split[2])*0.52918
        z = float(line_split[3])*0.52918

        col5 = line_split[4].strip()

        out_string = (
            '<marker id="{}" x="{}" y="{}" z="{}"'
            ' r="1" g="1" b="0" radius="0.125"/>\n'
        )

        if col5 == '3':
            out_string = (
               '<marker id="{}" x="{}" y="{}" z="{}"'
               ' r="0" g="0" b="1" radius="0.125"/>\n'
            )
         
        outfile.write(out_string.format(index, x, y, z))
            
    outfile.write('</marker_set>\n')
```